# Finding the distribution when $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem:

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with expected value equal to $1$ and variance equal to $1$. Find the distribution when $n$ goes to infinity of:

$$n^{3/2}\left(\frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n - n}{3(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)^2}\right)$$

Not sure how to proceed. I have the feeling it's normal distribution with mean $0$ but not sure about the variance or if this is even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the expression as
$$
Y_n=\frac{X_{1}+\dotsb+X_n-n}{\sqrt{n}}\biggr/\frac{3(X_1+\dotsb+X_n)^2}{n^2}
$$
and use [Slutsky's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) theorem. Specifically,
$$
\frac{X_{1}+\dotsb+X_n-n}{\sqrt{n}}\stackrel{d}{\to} Z\sim N(0,1)
$$
by the central limit theorem and
$$
\frac{3(X_1+\dotsb+X_n)^2}{n^2}\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\to} 3 
$$
by the SLLN and in particular in probability. Hence Slutsky's theorem implies that $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\to} Z/3.
$

Comment: thank you so much!